# How to test a function inside a default function of a Worker in Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme, web-worker

I have a Javascript file, `sortWorker.js`, of the following format:

```
export default () => {

    function sortData (data) {
        //some computation here

        return sortedData
    }

    self.addEventListener ("message", e => {
        postMessage(sortData(e.data))
    })
}
```

I am trying to test the `sortData()` function in isolation in Jest, but I am struggling to achieve this. Since this is a worker file, I cannot move `sortData` outside the `export default` scope. 
Could someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: i've never make use of web-worker... can't you create an object with `sortData` as a property and return it in your default function?

Comment: I tried returning the return value of `sortData` i.e. `sortedData` in the default function. This did not work either. Do you think putting this into an object will make a difference?

Comment: yes, so you can call it wherever you want..

Answer (score 0):

Try to return your function so you can call it right inside your test:

```
export default () => {

    const sortData = function (data) {
        //some computation here

        return sortedData
    }

    self.addEventListener ("message", e => {
        postMessage(sortData(e.data))
    })

    return { sortData };
}
```

So in your test you can call `sortData(data)` and assert its results.

---

EDIT: the OP asked to involve it in a sctruture. You could make something like:

**sort.js**

```
export default () => {

  const sortData = function (data) {
    return data.sort();
  }

  return { sortData };
}
```

**sort.test.js**

```
import sort from './sort';

const sortFn = sort().sortData;

const resp = sortFn([4, 3, 2, 1]);

console.log(resp); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you kindly add a code sample of how I can import the file and call the `sortData()` function for testing? I am a bit confused here

Comment: @Jspake Ok. added it. You basically import, invoke, then use it. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again. This did not seem to work. I am getting the error `Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined]`
Both sort function and other functions down the component tree use `map` and `foreach`